# Export reports (pdf, xml, html)

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, birt, export-to-pdf

Using MySQL with tables such as company, accounts, transactions, and splits.

Java Servlet on a Glassfish server, with Spring and EJB frameworks.

Goal: Produce PDF, HTML and XML formatted version of balance sheets, profit and loss, etc.

For maximum flexibility I can use a PDF library (like iText or PDFBox) that produces the reports, but I would prefer using a report editor with a report generation library where I can re-use as much framework/library functionality as possible.

Thinking about Eclipse BIRT or JasperReports.

Would like to read about solutions, including experiences of using those report packages.

Am especially interested in reading about experiences with existing report types, balance sheet/profit and loss.

### Loose Requirements

- Free or Open Source, but not necessarily
- Documented or commercially supported